Does Hittite ever have "morphographemic writings"?
In Akkadian, we often see "morphographemic" spellings, where signs are divided up by morpheme boundaries instead of syllable boundaries. For example, išpur=am "he sent it to me" can be written iš-pur-am, even though the expected syllabification is iš-pu-ram.
Does this ever happen in Hittite? That is, are signs ever divided at clitic boundaries instead of syllable boundaries? The main place I can imagine this happening is with the "Old Hittite non-geminating -a" that could be attached to nouns and pronouns to indicate a contrast; is uk=a ever written uk-a instead of u-ka?

It's probably worth noting that the frequency of these spellings also varies in Akkadian depending on period, region, type of text, scribal tradition and the specific signs involved. For example, in the genres I'm most familiar with, the spelling I'd expect would be iš-pu-ra-am, neither PUR nor RAM being particularly common signs. (FWIW, the PUR sign is simpler and perhaps more common than RAM, so one plausible explanation for iš-pur-am could simply be that the writer knew and remembered the sign PUR but not RAM. Although they may have remembered it because of išpur = "he sent", so...)

@IlmariKaronen Yeah, that's the sort of thing I'm thinking of—when the scribe's knowledge of išpur leads to a spelling like iš-pur-am or iš-pu-ur-am etc, actually just writing išpur and then adding am to the end. (Though whether it's sign knowledge or word knowledge affecting this is a good question too.)

It's rare, but it does happen. For example, eš-er "they were" (be-3P.PRF) is normally written e-še-er, but can also be written e-eš-er, since there's a very transparent boundary between the verb and its ending.
